# [InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: invalid base64 for part #2 (Property 'atob' doesn't exist)]

Tags: react-native, jwt

I am implementing `Apple login` using `react-native` and need to extract the email value of the user, so I am using `jwt-decode` to read the token file and read the email value. How do I `extract` the `token file` from react-native?
The library you use is

```json
    "react-native": "0.71.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, this is because standard libraries are missing, I solved it this way:

```
npm install core-js
```

after installation insert the following import into the file where the decode takes place

```
import "core-js/stable/atob";
```

example:

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import "core-js/stable/atob";
```